# Controlling UI controls (Lables, panels, buttons) and reading UI elements through a thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have seen similar questions. But none of them worked for me so far. I am doing some complex calculations in a separate thread. In order to do so, I need some information from the main UI thread. For example, during the calculation in the second thread, I have to hide and show some panels in the  UI. I also need to get the SerialPort number where an extra device connected and reading data through serial port.

```
private void ThreadedMethodForCalc()
{
if (InvokeRequired)
{
  this.Invoke(new Action(() => MethodToHideAllPanels())); //this work
//now I wanna show a panel named MainPanel
//how to do it?
//serialPort1.PortName = CBoxForPortName.SelectedItem.ToString();  //this wont't work inisde thread

//CBoxForPortName is in the Form. I want to read the value inside Thread
//also how to read the serial port inside the thread //serialPort1.Open();

}          
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access UI elements from any other thread than the one on which they were originally created. You may marshal calls to UI thread from your background thread, but you cannot modify the UI element directly from the background thread.

So you will have to use `Invoke` to grab the value from the UI thread, store it in a variable and then use it on your background thread, e.g.:

```
string s;
Invoke(new Action(() => s = CBoxForPortName.SelectedItem.ToString()));
serialPort1.PortName = s;
```